# gradle swallowing exception traces from scalatest tests

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest

I have this in my build.gradle:

```
 test {
   testLogging {
     exceptionFormat 'full'
     showExceptions true
     showStackTraces true
   }
 }
```

This works with java ("plain" junit) tests, but when I running scalatest tests, even with `-i` on command line, all I get in case of a failure is something like this:

```
com.mypackage.mytests.ScalatestSpec >  .apply should fail miserably FAILED
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: 2 was not equal to 1
```

No traceback or even a line number is printed out, and I have to rerun the test manually to be able to see where it actually failed. 
Is there another special flag I have to set to get it to stop following my output?

Comment: I don't know about a flag, but try reading a test report (`build/reports/tests/index.html`), it should contain relevant details.

Comment: The question is not where to find the output (I can just run the test manually), it is how to get gradle not to swallow it (so that, for example, an CI build can tell me what went wrong)

Comment: Oh, OK. Then try setting `test { testLogging { showStandardStreams = true } }`.

Comment: Done that. No difference :(

Comment: Dima did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @LogicalFallacy   No, I gave up on gradle. It's complete piece of junk ... buggy, undocumented, unsupported ... Switched to sbt and never looked back. 
Get out while can.

Comment: To readers in 2021+ (Gradle 6.8) - the actual excerpt in the question (`testLogging`) seems enough now.